# Сокращенный адрес при get-запросе

Tags: веб-программирование, http, url, get

Реализую одностраничный сайтик.
После ввода инфы, происходят ajax-запросы, по дальнейшей логике буду менять url в строке браузера на типа такой: `https://www.example.com/?id=1234567`

Так вот интересует вопрос, корректно ли так его задавать?
Во всех ли браузерах всё будет с этим нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, всё должно быть нормально.

Comment: Не ответ, а комментарий :Р

Comment: @Visman а чем это не ответ?

Comment: @VostokSisters, тем что комментарий :)

Comment: @Visman не понимаю. Вопрос не большой, ответ тоже. В чем проблема-то? Я понимаю, что это лёгкая репутация и всё такое. Но ответ на мой вопрос дан прекрасно чисто и быстро.

Comment: @VostokSisters, вот еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/677437/186083 один хороший вопрос ;)

Comment: @Visman ничего страшного. Кто захочет, тот ответит, я считаю. Как известно, глупых вопросов не бывает, есть только незаданные.

Comment: @Visman вон тебе порекомендовали в ответы кинуть ответ. Что вполне логично)