# Использование переменных в $_POST

Tags: php, post

Можно ли в $_POST[name] вместо name поместить переменную?

Comment: Можно. (и еще 9 символов)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а эта переменная может быть integer или только строковая?

Comment: @Visman, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @Александр, можно и число, и строку.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вопрос слишком простой.

Comment: @Visman, и что, простые вопросы должны оставаться неотвеченными и удаляться Духом?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ага. P.S. Пусть отвечают у кого репутации нет/мало.

Comment: `$_POST` - это ассоциативный массив........... можно ли в ассоциативном массиве в качестве ключа указать переменную?....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итог.

`$_POST` - это ассоциативный массив данных, переданных скрипту через HTTP метод POST.
В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php) написано, что ключом для ассоциативного массива может быть:

> либо типа integer, либо типа string

Значит следующий код будет работать и для $_POST

```
$intKey = 1;
$_POST[$intKey] = "test"

$stringKey = "key";
$_POST[$stringKey] = "test 2"
```